# universal compression and decompression

Tags: python, .net, zlib, msgpack

I'm building an excel plugin in .NET which is powered by django server for network calls.
The plugin would make post data calls to django server and the data returned is populated in the plugin appropriately.

I want to reduce the size of post data for making calls faster. This has huge impact. I thought of using msgpack for serializing and then use zlib to compress the serialized text.

I'm having a hard time to uncompress and unpack the data sent by plugin in python.

Is there a universal serializer and compression algos which work everywhere?

for example zlib compressed string in windows

```
eF6rVkosSi9WsoquVirJTM5OLVKyUkpMLMhR0lHKTS0pykwG8otSy1LzSlOBQgWpRZn5KUpWeaU5OTBeSWVBKkSkNrYWAC+NG7Q=
```

when i try to decompress in python using zlib.decompress it would raise error

```
Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Comment: If it's IPC you are looking into, you should look into things like Protobuffers, I've heard of Cap'n proto being used for this kind of an application but I'm not certain about it.